# Can I refer to a local field in condition element written in SpEL?

Tags: spring, spring-el

With following codes,

```java
@EventListener(condition = "#event.type == T(...MyDomainEvent.Type).INSERTED")
void inserted(final MyDomainEvent<T> event) {
    // 
}

protected final Class<?> sourceType;
```

Can I compare `sourceType` and `event.getSource().getClass()` in the condition element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot refer to field values in a generic sense; you can, however, if you know the bean name since the evaluation context has a bean resolver...

```
@Bean
public Foo fooBean() {
    return new Foo();
}

public static class Foo {

    public String sourceType = "xxx";

    @EventListener(condition = "@fooBean.sourceType.equals('xxx')")
    public void inserter(Object event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }

    protected String getSourceType() {
        return this.sourceType;
    }

    protected void setSourceType(String sourceType) {
        this.sourceType = sourceType;
    }

}
```